# How to replace current with DI in ReactiveMongo 0.11.11 & Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I used the [DAO](https://gist.github.com/almeidap/5685801) design GitHub Gist by [almeidap](https://gist.github.com/almeidap) as an example for my database layer. Unfortunately, `current` is deprecated since the Play release 2.5, so I can't use:

```
trait MongoHelper extends ContextHelper{

    lazy val db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db

}
```

nor

```
trait MongoHelper extends ContextHelper {

  lazy val reactiveMongoApi = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]

  lazy val db = reactiveMongoApi.db

}
```

Since I cannot inject `reactiveMongoApi` into a trait I am wondering how I can solve this issue. Despite the fact that the use of deprecated method is discouraged, I cannot start my application because I get the exception `There is no started application` caused by my startup code which inserts dummy data into my database on app launch.

Comment: You can have an abstract `def reactiveMongoApi` in the trait, the implementation class having to define it appriately, possibly using DI (as indicated in the [doc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html)).